# Show that $E$ is orientable.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, orientation

Suppose $(E,M,\pi)$ is a vector bundle and $M$ can be written as a union of two open subspaces $U$ and $V$ such that $U\cap V$ is connected. Assume that the restrictions of $E$ to $U$ and $V$ are orientable. I am stuck at this problem.

> Show that $E$ is orientable.

What I know about orientability:

1. vector bundle $(E,M,\pi)$ of rank $n$ is orientable iff $\Lambda^nE^\ast$ is isomorphic to the trivial bundle of rank $1$ over $M$.
2. Suppose $(E, M, \pi)$ is a vector bundle and $J:(E, M,\pi)\rightarrow (E, M,\pi)$ is a homomorphism such that $J\circ J=-id$. Then $E$ is orientable.

My initial thought was to use these above two facts to conclude $E$ is orientable. However I couldn't go further than this. Any suggestion or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to include what you have done and precisely where you are stuck. In particular, state precisely the criterion for orientability you are using and show where you cannot establish this criterion.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry about that. I have added what I know and more explanation.

Comment: It is clear your second point is useless in this situation, as you don't have $J$. Do you know the definition of orientability?

Comment: Forget 2. If you have a trivial line bundle on $U$ and a trivial line bundle on $V$, do they glue to make a trivial bundle if $U\cap V$ is connected?

Comment: @ArcticChar True. Point 2 is not going to help. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot for the hints.